# How to find links on a page, push them to array and open by each click 5 links from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am looking for a way how to open few links in new tabs by one click.

Here is some HTML-code I wrote.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://ebay.com">Ebay</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<a href="#" onclick="">Open all links above by one click!</a>
```

**UPD:** If it is possible, it would be great if it will search all links on a page wrapped with `<li></li>`, push them to array, and after a click link should open next 4 links from array.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/R7qFv/)

Comment: Sounds rather spammy. Why would anyone want that?

Comment: @Diodeus Home website maybe but browser already have this functionally in..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this works for me (based on the updated request): http://jsfiddle.net/R7qFv/4/

This keeps track of which links have been opened, so each time you click the link, it will open the next 4 in the list.

```
$("#openlinks").on("click", (function(){
    var count = 0, nAtOnce = 4, $links = $("li a");
    var openLinks = function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < nAtOnce && count < $links.length; i++) {
            window.open($links.eq(count++).attr("href"), '_blank');
        }
    };
    return openLinks;
})());
```

I wrote it using jQuery because it's easier for me, but I'm sure you can translate if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Without questioning your motives (because you will be blocked by the popup blocker),

```
function open4links () {
    var links = ['http://...', 'http://...', 'http://...', 'http://...'];
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        window.open(links[i], '_blank');
    }
}

(the a element).onclick = open4links;
```

Answer (score 1):

using `window.open`:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li a').each(function(){
        window.open($(this).attr("href"), '_blank');
    });
});
```

As you can see in the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8U7M4/1/), most browsers won't accept this because it is considered spam.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to find all links in your html code and open in other window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenLinks(){
    var arr = [];

    $("#list a").each(function(){
            arr.push(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
    });

    for(var i =0; i < arr.length;i++){
        window.open(arr[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

obs: use jquery!